# convert timestamp value in EL to date time in jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

```
  2014-02-26 18:27:24
```

jsp page

```
 <html>

 timestamp is : ${timestamp}

 Date is : <b> date   </b>  //display date

 Time is : <b> time   </b>  //display time

 </html>
```

how to convert date and time from timestamp (EL)?

Comment: Google for "JSTL date" and click.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [JSP Standard Tag Library](https://jstl.java.net/) [Formatting Tags](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakw.html#bnalc) that provides a set of tags for parsing and formatting locale-sensitive numbers and dates.

If you have Date String then parse it into Date Object.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>

<c:set value="2014-02-26 18:27:24" var="dateString" />

<fmt:parseDate value="${dateString}" var="dateObject"
                pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" />

Date is : <b><fmt:formatDate value="${dateObject }" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" /></b>
Time is : <b><fmt:formatDate value="${dateObject }" pattern="hh:mm a" /></b>
```

---

If you have time in milliseconds then convert in into Date Object.

```
<jsp:useBean id="dateObject" class="java.util.Date" />
<jsp:setProperty name="dateObject" property="time" value="${timeInMilliSeconds}" />

Date is : <b><fmt:formatDate value="${dateObject }" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" /></b>
Time is : <b><fmt:formatDate value="${dateObject }" pattern="hh:mm a" /></b>
```

output:

> Date is : **26/02/2014** Time is : **06:27 PM**