# JSP function to get month from timestamp

Tags: jsp, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have a time stamp column in cloud SQL database , Now i am trying to display a month wise graph on a JSP Page. Now for this graphical representation i need to extract month from the database time stamp column. Does anyone have a JSP function to extract month from the time stamp ?

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone have a JSP function to extract month from the time stamp ?

In JSP, you can use [JSTL Formatting Tags](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakw.html#bnalc) that provides a set of tags for parsing and formatting locale-sensitive numbers and dates.

Steps to follow:

1. first create a Date Object from Date String or long (time in milli seconds)
2. extract the month from the Date Object

Sample code:

```
<c:set value="10/23/2014 - 15:15:22" var="dateString" />

<fmt:parseDate value="${dateString}" var="dateObject"
    pattern="MM/dd/yyyy - HH:mm:ss" />

<fmt:formatDate value="${dateObject}" pattern="MM" />
```

---

Read more at my another post to create a Date object from Date String and long (time in milli seconds).

- [convert timestamp value in EL to date time in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341319/convert-timestamp-value-in-el-to-date-time-in-jsp/24341744#24341744)

Answer (score 0):

The excellent Joda DateTime library has a supplemental library for jsp tags which you could use.

[Check them out here](http://www.joda.org/joda-time-jsptags/userguide.html)