# java jsp convert string into time (or date?)

Tags: java, string, jsp, date

Good morning, I'm try to make a jsp page that read from a text a string value in format mm:ss; after, it must convert this string in type time because this value must be saved in a postgres column of type time; now the code is the following:

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page import="java.text.*"%>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="prova.jsp">
<input name="tempo" type="text" />
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Inserisci">
</form>

String tempoperc=request.getParameter("tempo");
Date data = null;            
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");            
data = df.parse(tempoperc);
```

when execute the jsp page I have the following error:

```
An exception occurred processing JSP page /prova.jsp at line that contain 
"data = df.parse(tempoperc);"
```

what is wrong?

Comment: What exact error do you get? What is the exact value of tempoperc? (Print it out, don't just assume you know what it is.)

Comment: How does your data in `tempoperc` look like? Consider printing it to make sure that it contains what it should contain.

Comment: what exception stacktrace says?

Comment: when I run on server don't compare the textbox but compare directly the error reporting that is the following:                          
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NullPointerException


type Exception report

message java.lang.NullPointerException

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service

Comment: org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


root cause 

java.lang.NullPointerException
 java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
 java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
 org.apache.jsp.inserisciassociazionefermata_005ffermata_jsp._jspService(inserisciassociazionefermata_005ffermata_jsp.java:167)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service

Comment: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Comment: As per exception `tempoperc` might be `null`

Comment: Braj, the problem is that tempoperc is null? I can't insert nothing because the textbox isn't loaded, is showed only the report

Comment: submit the request to the Servlet and do your processing there related to database insertion because JSP is not a good place to do all the business logic and database operation. Keep JSP just for UI purpose.

Comment: this isn't a servlet...it's java code into html code

Comment: As I said try to avoid Scriplet in 21st century. you are accessing the param value before submitting the request in the same jsp, Isn't it? How it will work? 1. When you click on submit button all the values from the form is posted to the requested servlet/jsp. 2. Access the values from request based in param name. Are you doing in this way?

Comment: Split your problem in 2. Create 2 JSP, one with the form submitting the value, and one with the logic ot manage data (the latter should be a servlet really). (Dividi il problema in 2, crea 2 jsp, la prima che posti i dati, la seconda che li processi, anche se sarebbe meglio una servlet per questo).

Comment: @Braj: so the problem is when I run the server it try to read a parameter that  is null...is right?

Comment: @BigMike why use 2 jsp. I suggest to use Servlet for database operation.

Comment: the project is made into jsp and I don't want use servlet.... however I have another problem: the type of variable is date but the type of column of postgres is time...how can make extract time from date to time into a trigger in pgplsql?

Comment: yes you have to check it first before parsing.

Comment: how can i make this checking?

Comment: @Braj servlet would be a better choice, I've spoked about 2 jsp for simplicity. From what I read OP probably is just a novice with servlet/jsp and probably is in the learning phase.

Comment: I know the use of servlet, but I have started the entire project into jsp e now I don't want migrate to servlet...now I must resolve another problem: how can make extract time from date to time into a trigger in pgplsql?

Answer (score 1):

As per exception trace :

> root cause java.lang.NullPointerException java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)

The root cause is that query parameter `tempo` is returning `null`.

How to reproduce the issue?

```
new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss").parse(null);
```

The above code results into the mentioned exception.

---

Always try to avoid Scriplet and use JSTL or EL. For *database operation* do it in the **Servlet** and simply submit the request to the Servlet.

In JSP, you can use [JSTL Formatting Tags](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakw.html#bnalc) that provides a set of tags for parsing and formatting locale-sensitive numbers and dates.

Read more at my another post to create a Date object from Date String and long (time in milli seconds).

- [convert timestamp value in EL to date time in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341319/convert-timestamp-value-in-el-to-date-time-in-jsp/24341744#24341744)

---

All the Scriplet codes are converted to HTML response before submitting the page back to client.

Now what will happen when page is accessed first time?

Since the form in not submitted hence the param value will be `null` and result into above exception.

Comment: Thena, I must insert in the text box only a time value that contain only minutes:seconds (for example 34:07 mean 34 minutes and 7 seconds)...I'm not interested to date,I have write date because seem that time type isn't available in java

Comment: I have overwrite new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss").parse(null); to new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss"); but now I have an error on the console: cannot convert from Date to DateFormat

Comment: As per your new error, it's compile time error that says that you can't not assign DateFormat object to Date. Does it make sense?